# C Segmentation fault, when the program is run in the terminal, but runs and returns 0 in Eclipse

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm working on a program that prints 2 strings on a ppm image file.
My program seems to work, when run in eclipse and i can see my image being updated, but when I run it in C, I get Segmentation fault(core dumped).

main.c:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include "font8x8_basic.h"
    #include "func.h"


int main(){

    ppm *h = store("image.ppm");
    printf("\n Header: %s %d, %d, %d \n Pixels: %d\n", h->type, h->width, h->height, h->color_max, *h->pixel_pointer);
    printchar(h, ' ', 0);
    char *str="Naruto does brrrr";

    for (int i=0; i<strlen(str); i++){
        ppm *s = store("out.ppm");
        printchar(s, *(str+i), (i)*10);

        }

    for (int i=0; i<strlen(str); i++){
            ppm *s = store("out.ppm");
            printchar(s, *(str+i), ((i)*10+(s->width)*(s->height-10)));
        }
    return 0;
}
```

func.h:

```
        #ifndef FUNC_H_
        #define FUNC_H_
    
    typedef struct ppm{
        //P3 = ASCII; P6 = BINARY
        char *type;
        //Will be used as matrix dimentions
        unsigned int width;
        unsigned int height;
        unsigned int color_max;
        unsigned int *pixel_pointer;
        unsigned int num_el;
    }ppm;
    
    void printchar(ppm *img, unsigned char ch, int offset){
        FILE *out = fopen("out.ppm", "w");
        fprintf(out,"%s \n%d %d\n%d\n ", img->type, img->width, img->height, img->color_max);
        int set;
        int x=0;
        int new_row=0;
        for(int c=1; c<((img->num_el/3)+x); c++){
            new_row = x*((img->width))+(img->width)/4+2+offset;
                 if((x<8)&&((c==new_row+x))){
                    for (int y=0; y < 8; y++) {
                        set = font8x8_basic[ch][x] & 1 << (y);
                             if(set){
                                fprintf(out, "%d %d %d ",0,0,0);
                                img->pixel_pointer = img->pixel_pointer+3;
                                }
                            else{
                                fprintf(out, "%d %d %d ",*img->pixel_pointer,*(img->pixel_pointer+1),*(img->pixel_pointer+2));
                                img->pixel_pointer = img->pixel_pointer+3;
                                }
                            c++;
                    }
                    x++;
                }
                else{
                     fprintf(out, "%d %d %d ",*img->pixel_pointer,*(img->pixel_pointer+1),*(img->pixel_pointer+2));
                     img->pixel_pointer = img->pixel_pointer+3;
                }
        }
    fclose(out);
    }
    
    unsigned int *endptr;
    
    ppm *store(char *filename){
    
        ppm *input_file = malloc(sizeof(ppm));
        input_file->type = malloc(sizeof(char)*3);
        FILE *fp= fopen(filename, "rb");
        fscanf(fp, "%s\n", input_file->type);
        fscanf(fp, "%d %d\n", &input_file->width, &input_file->height);
        fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &input_file->color_max);
        int i=0;
        input_file->pixel_pointer = malloc((input_file->width)*(input_file->height)*sizeof(unsigned int)*3);
    
        for(int c=0; c<(3*(input_file->width)*(input_file->height)); c++){
    
                fscanf(fp, "%d ", (input_file->pixel_pointer+i));
    
                        i++;
        }
        input_file->num_el = i;
    
        fclose(fp);
    
        return input_file;
    }
```

GDB and Valgrind point to my second call of the store() function for the segmentation fault.

Any help would be appreciated!

edit: font8x8_basic.h:

```
char font8x8_basic[128][8] = {
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+0000 (nul)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+0001
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+0002
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+0003
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+0004
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+0005
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+0006
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+0007
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+0008
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+0009
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+000A
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+000B
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+000C
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+000D
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+000E
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+000F
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+0010
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+0011
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+0012
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+0013
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+0014
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+0015
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+0016
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+0017
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+0018
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+0019
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+001A
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+001B
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+001C
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+001D
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+001E
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+001F
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+0020 (space)
    { 0x18, 0x3C, 0x3C, 0x18, 0x18, 0x00, 0x18, 0x00},   // U+0021 (!)
    { 0x36, 0x36, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+0022 (")
    { 0x36, 0x36, 0x7F, 0x36, 0x7F, 0x36, 0x36, 0x00},   // U+0023 (#)
    { 0x0C, 0x3E, 0x03, 0x1E, 0x30, 0x1F, 0x0C, 0x00},   // U+0024 ($)
    { 0x00, 0x63, 0x33, 0x18, 0x0C, 0x66, 0x63, 0x00},   // U+0025 (%)
    { 0x1C, 0x36, 0x1C, 0x6E, 0x3B, 0x33, 0x6E, 0x00},   // U+0026 (&)
    { 0x06, 0x06, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+0027 (')
    { 0x18, 0x0C, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x0C, 0x18, 0x00},   // U+0028 (()
    { 0x06, 0x0C, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x0C, 0x06, 0x00},   // U+0029 ())
    { 0x00, 0x66, 0x3C, 0xFF, 0x3C, 0x66, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+002A (*)
    { 0x00, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x3F, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+002B (+)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x06},   // U+002C (,)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3F, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+002D (-)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x00},   // U+002E (.)
    { 0x60, 0x30, 0x18, 0x0C, 0x06, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00},   // U+002F (/)
    { 0x3E, 0x63, 0x73, 0x7B, 0x6F, 0x67, 0x3E, 0x00},   // U+0030 (0)
    { 0x0C, 0x0E, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x3F, 0x00},   // U+0031 (1)
    { 0x1E, 0x33, 0x30, 0x1C, 0x06, 0x33, 0x3F, 0x00},   // U+0032 (2)
    { 0x1E, 0x33, 0x30, 0x1C, 0x30, 0x33, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+0033 (3)
    { 0x38, 0x3C, 0x36, 0x33, 0x7F, 0x30, 0x78, 0x00},   // U+0034 (4)
    { 0x3F, 0x03, 0x1F, 0x30, 0x30, 0x33, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+0035 (5)
    { 0x1C, 0x06, 0x03, 0x1F, 0x33, 0x33, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+0036 (6)
    { 0x3F, 0x33, 0x30, 0x18, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x00},   // U+0037 (7)
    { 0x1E, 0x33, 0x33, 0x1E, 0x33, 0x33, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+0038 (8)
    { 0x1E, 0x33, 0x33, 0x3E, 0x30, 0x18, 0x0E, 0x00},   // U+0039 (9)
    { 0x00, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x00},   // U+003A (:)
    { 0x00, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x06},   // U+003B (;)
    { 0x18, 0x0C, 0x06, 0x03, 0x06, 0x0C, 0x18, 0x00},   // U+003C (<)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x3F, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3F, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+003D (=)
    { 0x06, 0x0C, 0x18, 0x30, 0x18, 0x0C, 0x06, 0x00},   // U+003E (>)
    { 0x1E, 0x33, 0x30, 0x18, 0x0C, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x00},   // U+003F (?)
    { 0x3E, 0x63, 0x7B, 0x7B, 0x7B, 0x03, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+0040 (@)
    { 0x0C, 0x1E, 0x33, 0x33, 0x3F, 0x33, 0x33, 0x00},   // U+0041 (A)
    { 0x3F, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3E, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3F, 0x00},   // U+0042 (B)
    { 0x3C, 0x66, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x66, 0x3C, 0x00},   // U+0043 (C)
    { 0x1F, 0x36, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x36, 0x1F, 0x00},   // U+0044 (D)
    { 0x7F, 0x46, 0x16, 0x1E, 0x16, 0x46, 0x7F, 0x00},   // U+0045 (E)
    { 0x7F, 0x46, 0x16, 0x1E, 0x16, 0x06, 0x0F, 0x00},   // U+0046 (F)
    { 0x3C, 0x66, 0x03, 0x03, 0x73, 0x66, 0x7C, 0x00},   // U+0047 (G)
    { 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x3F, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x00},   // U+0048 (H)
    { 0x1E, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+0049 (I)
    { 0x78, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x33, 0x33, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+004A (J)
    { 0x67, 0x66, 0x36, 0x1E, 0x36, 0x66, 0x67, 0x00},   // U+004B (K)
    { 0x0F, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x46, 0x66, 0x7F, 0x00},   // U+004C (L)
    { 0x63, 0x77, 0x7F, 0x7F, 0x6B, 0x63, 0x63, 0x00},   // U+004D (M)
    { 0x63, 0x67, 0x6F, 0x7B, 0x73, 0x63, 0x63, 0x00},   // U+004E (N)
    { 0x1C, 0x36, 0x63, 0x63, 0x63, 0x36, 0x1C, 0x00},   // U+004F (O)
    { 0x3F, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3E, 0x06, 0x06, 0x0F, 0x00},   // U+0050 (P)
    { 0x1E, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x3B, 0x1E, 0x38, 0x00},   // U+0051 (Q)
    { 0x3F, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3E, 0x36, 0x66, 0x67, 0x00},   // U+0052 (R)
    { 0x1E, 0x33, 0x07, 0x0E, 0x38, 0x33, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+0053 (S)
    { 0x3F, 0x2D, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+0054 (T)
    { 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x3F, 0x00},   // U+0055 (U)
    { 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x1E, 0x0C, 0x00},   // U+0056 (V)
    { 0x63, 0x63, 0x63, 0x6B, 0x7F, 0x77, 0x63, 0x00},   // U+0057 (W)
    { 0x63, 0x63, 0x36, 0x1C, 0x1C, 0x36, 0x63, 0x00},   // U+0058 (X)
    { 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x1E, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+0059 (Y)
    { 0x7F, 0x63, 0x31, 0x18, 0x4C, 0x66, 0x7F, 0x00},   // U+005A (Z)
    { 0x1E, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+005B ([)
    { 0x03, 0x06, 0x0C, 0x18, 0x30, 0x60, 0x40, 0x00},   // U+005C (\)
    { 0x1E, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+005D (])
    { 0x08, 0x1C, 0x36, 0x63, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+005E (^)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF},   // U+005F (_)
    { 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x18, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+0060 (`)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x1E, 0x30, 0x3E, 0x33, 0x6E, 0x00},   // U+0061 (a)
    { 0x07, 0x06, 0x06, 0x3E, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3B, 0x00},   // U+0062 (b)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x1E, 0x33, 0x03, 0x33, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+0063 (c)
    { 0x38, 0x30, 0x30, 0x3e, 0x33, 0x33, 0x6E, 0x00},   // U+0064 (d)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x1E, 0x33, 0x3f, 0x03, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+0065 (e)
    { 0x1C, 0x36, 0x06, 0x0f, 0x06, 0x06, 0x0F, 0x00},   // U+0066 (f)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x6E, 0x33, 0x33, 0x3E, 0x30, 0x1F},   // U+0067 (g)
    { 0x07, 0x06, 0x36, 0x6E, 0x66, 0x66, 0x67, 0x00},   // U+0068 (h)
    { 0x0C, 0x00, 0x0E, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+0069 (i)
    { 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x33, 0x33, 0x1E},   // U+006A (j)
    { 0x07, 0x06, 0x66, 0x36, 0x1E, 0x36, 0x67, 0x00},   // U+006B (k)
    { 0x0E, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+006C (l)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x33, 0x7F, 0x7F, 0x6B, 0x63, 0x00},   // U+006D (m)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x1F, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x00},   // U+006E (n)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x1E, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+006F (o)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x3B, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3E, 0x06, 0x0F},   // U+0070 (p)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x6E, 0x33, 0x33, 0x3E, 0x30, 0x78},   // U+0071 (q)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x3B, 0x6E, 0x66, 0x06, 0x0F, 0x00},   // U+0072 (r)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x3E, 0x03, 0x1E, 0x30, 0x1F, 0x00},   // U+0073 (s)
    { 0x08, 0x0C, 0x3E, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x2C, 0x18, 0x00},   // U+0074 (t)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x6E, 0x00},   // U+0075 (u)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x1E, 0x0C, 0x00},   // U+0076 (v)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x63, 0x6B, 0x7F, 0x7F, 0x36, 0x00},   // U+0077 (w)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x63, 0x36, 0x1C, 0x36, 0x63, 0x00},   // U+0078 (x)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x3E, 0x30, 0x1F},   // U+0079 (y)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x3F, 0x19, 0x0C, 0x26, 0x3F, 0x00},   // U+007A (z)
    { 0x38, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x07, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x38, 0x00},   // U+007B ({)
    { 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x00, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x00},   // U+007C (|)
    { 0x07, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x38, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x07, 0x00},   // U+007D (})
    { 0x6E, 0x3B, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+007E (~)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}    // U+007F
};
```

Comment: Assuming you're hoping to read something like "P3" for the type two characters worth of space is not enough here: `input_file->type = malloc(sizeof(char)*2);` You need at least 3 characters to allow for the terminating 0.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have added it.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thank you for the suggestion!
I tried it wit 3,4 and 5 but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: @slasherer Good! I'm not sure if it's relevant to your case or not but if you use `g++` or `clang++` you can add the compilator options `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` when you are debugging and you may get a much better insight into what's causing the problem at runtime. It could look [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/6Pqo3W9rT) which points at the `fscanf(fp, "%s\n", input_file->type);` line in the `store` function.

Comment: I'm still trying to wrap my head around that `c++;` buried in the middle of that inner loop. Also, the amount of memory being leaked in this program is hideous. Look at those loops in `main`. Each call to `store` loads the provided `ppm` (assuming many things, among them existence; there is zero error checking), and subsequently leaks everything. You're also playing with fire with the no-fewer-than a dozen warnings about signed/unsigned intermix. Those aren't mere suggestions; they're telling you you're doing something *wrong*.